# Are there ASP.NET controls that can display an RSS feed inside an existing ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net, rss

Are there ASP.NET controls that can display an RSS feed inside an existing ASPX page?
Ideally, it would render simply --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial

http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2010/01/read-or-consume-rss-feed-in-aspnet-2035.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this out... I haven't used it but it comes from a good source:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/22/Awesome-ASP.NET-2.0-RSS-Tool_2D00_Kit-Released.aspx